# Apex approval process that requires unanimous approval from multiple approvers

Tags: apex, approval-process

Once every few months this requirement appears as part of a project. Here is some sample code:

```
trigger AfterUpdate on Contact (After update) {

    for(Contact newContact: Trigger.new){

        Contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(newContact.id);

        if (oldContact.mailingStreet <> newContact.mailingStreet) {
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();

            req.setComments('Approving an address change.');
            req.setObjectId(newContact.id);
            req.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{'005i0000000h5az', '005i0000000hASk'});

            Approval.ProcessResult res = Approval.process(req);
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following error message:

```
Error:Apex trigger AfterUpdate caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AfterUpdate: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, missing required field: []: Trigger.AfterUpdate: line 14, column 1
```

If you change the list in the `setNextApproverIds` method parameter to only have a single ID then this error disappears.

This begs the question, can you require multiple approvers through Apex? And if so, how?

For added context, there is only one approval step and the details are:

[image: Approval Step Details]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might this statement in the docs for the ProcessRequest class, the parent class for the ProcessSubmitRequest, provide some insight?

> If the next step in your approval process is another Apex approval process, you specify exactly one user ID as the next approver.

[ProcessRequest class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ProcessRequest.htm)

---

**Update:**

One method to do this would be to rearrange the trigger behavior to create a single process request per approver and then use the process method overload which takes a list parameter.

```
trigger AfterUpdate on Contact (After update) {

    for(Contact newContact: Trigger.new){

        Contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(newContact.id);

        if (oldContact.mailingStreet <> newContact.mailingStreet) {
            List<Id> approverIds = new List<Id>{'005i0000000h5az', '005i0000000hASk'};
            List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest> requests = new List<Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest>();

            for (Id approverId : approverIds) {
                Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();

                req.setComments('Approving an address change.');
                req.setObjectId(newContact.id);
                req.setNextApproverIds(new List<Id>{approverId});

                requests.add(req);
            }

            List<Approval.ProcessResult> results = Approval.process(requests);
        }
    }
}
```

Would this suffice for your scenario?

Comment: I don't think so, the code above is all the code I'm using.

Comment: Well, if your next step is another apex approval process, the code you are leveraging will inherit this restriction from it's parent class. Even though the ProcessSubmitRequest class doesn't explicitly mention this caveat, the class inheritance and the behavior you're seeing would lead me to believe this is the reason it only works with a single ID. What is your next process step?

Comment: Updated my post to add more info. Let me know what else you might need.

Comment: That'll do the trick :)

Comment: I used the same suggestion as described here. In general, this does the trick, however, it's not really the same as a usual unanimous approval process since the final approval / rejection actions you would specify would already be executed even after the first person approves. Any suggestions how you would handle that? So being able to know if all of your users you submitted the record too have approved a specific approval process?

Comment: @KoenVM can you create a new question so that we can get more information about the unanimous approver process problem that you're trying to solve? You can link to this question if you want to use it for additional context for your new question.

Comment: @MarkPond done : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31463/issue-with-final-approval-rejection-action-with-unanimous-approval-through-ape

Comment: Please note that this solution initiates multiple copies of the approval process.  If you send 2 approval requests and the first if approved or rejected, the second will remain pending, and you will not be able to submit to other approval processes.  See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50634/any-way-to-recall-arbitrary-approval-requests-from-trigger for more details.