# Submitting an Account Record into an approval when the Account Rating on warm Approved send an email automatically

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting

[image]

### Apex Class:-

```
global class SAPRequest{
WebService static void SendApprovalRequest(string id) {
// create the new approval request to submit
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
req.setComments('Submitted for approval. Please approve.');
 req.setObjectId(id);
// submit the approval request for processing
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(req);

// display if the reqeust was successful
System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());
}
}
```

Submitting an Account into an approval when the Account Rating on warm send an email Error is

> System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, missing required field

Comment: Possible duplicate https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17596/required-field-missing-error-when-approval-process-set-to-manually-select

Comment: This question is seriously lacking in detail.

Answer (score 0):

In Approval Steps, if Assigned Approver is selected as "Manually Chosen" then you must set `req.setNextApproverIds(ID[])`  as well in your approval call.

Comment: still the issue not clear Ayub Ansari

Comment: global class SAPRequest{
WebService static void SendApprovalRequest(string id) {
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
req.setComments('Submitted for approval. Please approve.');
 req.setObjectId(id);
 req.setNextApproverIds(Id[]);
// submit the approval request for processing
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.Process(req);
// display if the reqeust was successful
System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());
}
} Error: Compile Error: Missing ')' at '[' at line 10 column 27