# Changing approval process approvers via Apex

Tags: apex, approval-process, dynamic

I'm trying to change the approvers for an approval process via Apex. Ideally I want to dynamically set **2 unanimous approvers** through code, but I can't figure it out.

I have the following code:

```
 public static void submitSplitApproval(Id recordId, List<Id> approverIds){

    approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
    req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
    req1.setObjectId(recordId);
    Id approver = approverIds[0];
    req1.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {approver});
    System.Debug(req1.getNextApproverIds());
    approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);

}
```

I have lifted the bulk of the code from this answer [here.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/apex-approval-process-that-requires-unanimous-approval-from-multiple-approvers)

System.Debug displays the expected user ID, but once it's submitted and I browse to the record it's still showing the old approver. Is there a way to add 2 unanimous approvers dynamically via Apex?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just curious, where is the second approver?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm passing a list of approverIds to the method, but I figured I'd try and get one approver updated and working beforehand.

Comment: Is this the same issue mentioned here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/apex-approval-process-that-requires-unanimous-approval-from-multiple-approvers

Comment: Similar, but I'm more interested in trying to chain the steps together in Apex.